# My express js api cannot read my given property

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

It does not read the `res.body.signatureRequestId` property for my Express js server.
How should I submit the property to avoid the error in type error? I shared my error log, json response, express js code with below.

Error log:

```
{
  account: {
    account_id: 'aaa',
    email_address: 'xxx@gmail.com',
    is_locked: false,
    is_paid_hs: false,
    is_paid_hf: false,
    quotas: {
      templates_left: 0,
      documents_left: 2,
      api_signature_requests_left: 0
    },
    callback_url: 'https://hellosigntest.info/api/callback',
    role_code: null
  },
  resHeaders: {
    'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
    'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    date: 'Fri, 10 Apr 2020 10:01:26 GMT',
    p3p: 'CP="NOP3PPOLICY"',
    server: 'Apache',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15768000',
    'user-agent': 'HelloSign API',
    vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
    'x-ratelimit-limit': '2000',
    'x-ratelimit-limit-remaining': '1999',
    'x-ratelimit-reset': '1586512887',
    'content-length': '329',
    connection: 'Close'
  },
  statusCode: 200,
  statusMessage: 'OK'
}
Hello API Event Received
TypeError: Cannot read property 'signature_request_id' of undefined
    at /Desktop/nodejs/helloSignDemo/routes/index.js:50:54
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Desktop/nodejs/helloSignDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Desktop/nodejs/helloSignDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Desktop/nodejs/helloSignDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Desktop/nodejs/helloSignDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Desktop/nodejs/helloSignDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Desktop/nodejs/helloSignDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Desktop/nodejs/helloSignDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Desktop/nodejs/helloSignDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Desktop/nodejs/helloSignDemo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

Events posted to your callback url will be formatted as a JSON string contained in the json POST param. The complete detail for the event object can be found in the event section of the API reference page. Here is an example of an event that could be received:

```
{
    "account_guid": "aaa", // DEPRECATED: use reported_for_account_id instead
    "client_id": null,  // DEPRECATED: use reported_for_app_id instead
    "event": {
        "event_time": "1348177752", 
        "event_type": "signature_request_sent",
        "event_hash": "aaa",
        "event_metadata": {
            "related_signature_id": "aaa", 
            "reported_for_account_id": "aaa",
            "reported_for_app_id": null
        }
    },


 signature_request: {
    signature_request_id: 'aaaaa',
    test_mode: true,
    title: 'PDF Sign via Node Server',
    original_title: 'PDF Sign via Node Server',
    subject: 'PDF Sign via Node Server',
    message: 'Please sign this pdf.',
    metadata: {},
    created_at: 1586507276,
    is_complete: false,
    is_declined: false,
    has_error: false,
    custom_fields: [],
    response_data: [],
    signing_url: 'https://xxxcom/aaa',
    signing_redirect_url: null,
    final_copy_uri: '/v3/signature_request/final_copy/aaa',
    files_url: 'https://api.hellosign.com/v3/signature_request/files/aaa',
    details_url: 'https://app.hellosign.com/home/manage?guid=aaa',
    requester_email_address: 'xxx@gmail.com',
    signatures: [ [Object] ],
    cc_email_addresses: [],
    template_ids: null
  }
}
```

routes/ index js :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const hellosign = require('hellosign-sdk')({ key: 'key' });
const fs = require('fs');

hellosign.account.update({
    callback_url: process.env.HOST_URL+'/api/callback'
}).then((res) => {
    // handle response
    console.log(res)
}).catch((err) => {
    // handle error
    console.log(err)
});

router.post('/sign',(req,res)=>{
    const opts = {
        test_mode: 1,
        title: 'PDF Sign via Node Server',
        subject: 'PDF Sign via Node Server',
        message: 'Please sign this pdf.',
        signers: [
            {
                email_address: 'xxx@gmail.com',
                name: 'xxx'
            }
        ],
        files: ['nda.pdf']
    };

    hellosign.signatureRequest.send(opts).then((res) => {
        // handle response
        console.log(res)
    }).catch((err) => {
        // handle error
        console.log(err)
    });
});

router.post('/callback',(req,res)=>{

    res.send('Hello API Event Received');

    res.send(res.body);

    try {
        hellosign.signatureRequest.download(res.body.signatureRequestId, { file_type: 'zip' }, (err, res) => {
            const file = fs.createWriteStream('files.zip');

            res.pipe(file);

            file.on('finish', () => {
                file.close();
            });
        });
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Server is listening...")
});

module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use('/api',require('./routes/index'));


app.listen(process.env.PORT,function(){
    console.log("Started on PORT "+process.env.PORT);
});
```

Comment: Do you realize that you can only call `res.send()` once per request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `res.body` property is not populated by default.  To get it populated from your POST data, you need an appropriate middleware that will read the body of the request, parse it and place the parsed results into req.body.

Express has a few middleware functions built-in that you can use as shown below:

```
app.use(express.json());                           // for json body
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));      // for form encoded body
app.use(express.text());                           // for plain text body
```

You need to use middleware that matches the content-type of your POST request.  That middleware will then populate the `req.body` property.

From the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body):

> **req.body**
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as express.json() or express.urlencoded().

As you can see in the documentation, `req.body` is `undefined` unless you have an appropriate middleware that matches in the incoming content-type and runs before your request handler.

Comment: first of all, thanks for the comment sir, I added my routes and index files separately to my question. Can you please look again? I used the middleware part you sent as a comment. I forgot to add it to my question.

Comment: @okoreni - What is the incoming content-type?

Comment: response comes as json. as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Should I change res.body.signatureRequestId to res.body.signature_request_id ? I'm having trouble with this.

Comment: Add `console.log(req.body)` in two places.  Add it at the very beginning of your POST route handler and then add it right before you do `hellosign.signatureRequest.download(res.body.signatureRequestId, {...})`.  You want to see if it ever has any values in it.

Comment: As for `res.body.signatureRequestId` vs `res.body.signature_request_id`, that depends entirely upon the JSON.  We don't know what's in your JSON.  You have to know what it will be.

Comment: i just added error log on my question, can you check please?

Comment: @okoreni - What is that output you call "error log"?  Where did that come from.  What code placed in what position?

Comment: i changed my callback method, i seperate them. /api/callback and /api/download. its okay now, very thank you.